# what does the class modifier do in cil call command?

Tags: cil

looking at the code generated by monodis, I see that the call to `Console.WriteLine` is translated to `call void class [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine`. I know that the `void` at the beginning is the return value, but what does the class mean?

Comment: I'd assume that `class` means this method is called **without an object context** tmt **a static method**. You may have a look at this tutorial at [codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3778/Introduction-to-IL-Assembly-Language#Object)

Comment: "class method" is a geeky way to say "static method".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `class` keyword just says that `System.Console` is a class.

The relevant part of [the CLI specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf) is §II.7.1 Types. It describes the *Type* rule of the CIL grammar, which requires `class` to refer to any "user defined reference type".

Though the `call` instruction actually takes a *TypeSpec*, which means that omitting the `class` keyword is also allowed.